# Trying to get main function to display a function in python

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point

I cant seem to get the main function to display the area function when I run the code.  It displays the radius function.  I have the area function use a variable from the radius function.

```
def radius(x, y, a, b):
    d = math.sqrt((x - a)**2 + (y - b)**2)
    print('The distance between the center points: ', d)


def area(d):
    pi = math.pi
    ar = pi * d**2
    print('The area of the circle: ', ar)


def main():
    print('Enter first coordinates:')
    x = int(input('Enter X: '))
    y = int(input('Enter Y: '))
    print('Enter second coordinates: ')
    a = int(input('Enter X: '))
    b = int(input('Enter Y: '))

    radius(x, y, a, b)
    area(d)

main()
```

Comment: Add `return ar` to radius, then `d = radius...` in main

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

If you want to use the variable d from your radius function, you must first return it from the radius function. and then "catch it" when calling the function. 
This enables you to use it in another context. See below:

```
def radius(x, y, a, b):
    d = math.sqrt((x - a)**2 + (y - b)**2)
    print('The distance between the center points: ', d)
    return d



def main():
    print('Enter first coordinates:')
    x = int(input('Enter X: '))
    y = int(input('Enter Y: '))
    print('Enter second coordinates: ')
    a = int(input('Enter X: '))
    b = int(input('Enter Y: '))

    d = radius(x, y, a, b)
    area(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an aspiring youngster in the Python world, you should try to get accustomed to using `return` statements. Growing up you will learn that you do not always need them, but let's leave that for later.

Here is your code corrected:

```
def radius(x, y, a, b):
    r = math.sqrt((x - a)**2 + (y - b)**2) / 2  # you call the function radius but calculate the diameter -> confusing!
    return r


def area(d):
    ar = math.pi * d**2
    return ar


def main():
    print('Enter first coordinates:')
    x = int(input('Enter X: '))
    y = int(input('Enter Y: '))
    print('Enter second coordinates: ')
    a = int(input('Enter X: '))
    b = int(input('Enter Y: '))

    D = 2 * radius(x, y, a, b)
    print('The distance between the center points: ', D)
    A = area(D)
    print('The area of the circle: ', A)
    return

main()
```

The problem with the original one, is that the `d` on `area(d)` call was not defined since `d` was not declared in that particular scope.

Comment: I see what I have been doing wrong with my code.  Not using the return and not defining the variables in the proper functions.  Thank you for the help!